# Do height-balanced binary trees have logarithmic depth?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

A family of binary trees is called balanced if for every tree $t$ in the family the height of $t$ is $O( \log n)$.

Given a family of trees such that for every tree $t$ in the family, for every node $v$ in $t$, the height difference between the right subtree of $v$ and the left subtree of $v$ is at most $c$, where $c$ is some constant.

I understand this claim is true. It is the general case for AVL trees. I just don't know how to prove it formally.

Comment: What is the claim you're trying to prove? Do you want to show that such a family is height balanced?

Comment: Yes Steven. Exactly. We need to prove that this family is height balanced.

Comment: Is this an infinite family? Big-O notation applies to asymptotic behavior, which doesn't apply to finite cases.

Answer (score 4):

Let us denote by $N_h$ the minimum number of leaves of a tree in your family of height $h$. Clearly $N_0 = 1$, and
$$ N_h = N_{h-1} + \min_{0 \leq d \leq c} N_{h-1-d}. $$
(Here $N_h = 0$ if $h < 0$.) You can prove inductively that $N_h$ is monotone, and so for $h \geq c+1$,
$$ N_h = N_{h-1} + N_{h-1-c}. $$
This is a recurrence relation whose solution is $N_h = \Theta(\alpha^h)$, where $\alpha$ is the maximal real root of $x^{c+1} - x^c - 1= 0$; for example, when $c = 1$, $x$ is the golden ratio.

Since the number of leaves in a tree of height $h$ is $\Omega(\alpha^h)$, it follows that a tree containing $n$ leaves has height $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Hey Yuval. Thank you. I have few questions: 1. Why we want to show that Nh is monotone? And to show that I need to prove that Nh+1 >= Nh?   2. How do I reach the expression a^h?

Comment: We want to show that $N_h$ is monotone so we could get a simpler recurrence relation for it. We can then solve it using classical techniques to get the answer $\Theta(\alpha^h)$. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_h$ be any tree that satisfies your property and has height at least $h$. Let $|T_h|$ be the number of its nodes.

For $0 \le h \le c$, $|T_h| \ge 1$.
For $h > c \cdot i$, with $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$, you have:
$$
|T_h| \ge 1 + | T_{c \cdot i} | + | T_{ c \cdot (i-1)}| \ge 2  | T'_{ c \cdot (i-1)}|,
$$
where $T_{c \cdot i}$, $T_{ c \cdot (i-1)}$, and $T'_{ c \cdot (i-1)}$ are  trees of height at least $c \cdot i$, $ c \cdot (i-1)$, and $ c \cdot (i-1)$, respectively, that also satisfy your property.

Let $T$ be a tree of height $H$ from your family. From the above observations (choosing $h=H$) it follows that $|T| \ge 2^{\left\lfloor \frac{H}{c+1} \right\rfloor} \ge 2^{\frac{H}{c+1} - 1}$, or equivalently, $H \le (c+1)( 1+ \log |T|)  = O(\log |T|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers. 
Finally I decided to take the proof of AVL tree has a height of O (log n ) and implenent the recurrence with the constant c. 
Basically Avl is a special case of this claim so taking the proof of AVL using the same idea led me to the proof. 
Instead of N(h) = N (h-1) + N (h-2) + 1
I used
N(h) = N ( h -1) + N ( h - 1 - c) + 1